# PostgreSQL 16 database will not run as service, must have a CMD open for it to work

Tags: postgresql, windows, cmd

I need some serious help here. Here is the laydown, I have a postgres database set up.
For some reason the server will not stay running as a service when attempting to start it in the services app (windows)

When I attempt to start as Local System I receive the "service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services etc."

I used my terminal to check the status always using

```
pg_ctl status -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data"
```

This tells me if the server is running, currently it is. However, if I close the command terminal the  server stops abruptly and I get this in the log.

2024-03-26 15:13:32.938 PDT [5348] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-03-26 15:06:17 PDT
2024-03-26 15:13:33.313 PDT [5348] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress

So then I go through having to open a new terminal and doing the following

```
pg_ctl start -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data"
```

to Start the server again, which I have to attempt a handful of times.

then use

```
pg_ctl status -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data"
```

to Monitor if the server is on, and then I have to leave that terminal open and alone in order for me to access the data via pgAdmin.

Any help is appreciated, there is currently a postmaster.pid file in there that was generated because I tried to start the service and made the terminal crash. In other words, they are not working well together. Any ideas on a fix?

I have tried the following:
Ensuring there is no postmaster.pid file in the \16\data path.
I shutdown the server using the ctrl_stop command
I then try and boot as a service and receive the
"service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services etc." Error message.

Comment: 1) Where did you install Postgres from? 2) Are you starting the service as Windows Admin user?

Comment: 1) I installed postgres standalone from the postgres site. 2) Reviewing this no, I think I would need IT to input admin rights to run as admin user. Perhaps I need to get with them and make sure we attempt that.